# Problema con llamada a métodos en clases anónimas y ámbito de las variables

Tags: php

```
<?php
include "conDBconsul.php";
if(isset($_POST['consulta'])){
  class creden extends conecta{
    function infoAlumnos(){
      $grade=$_POST['grado'];
      $group=$_POST['grupo'];
      $alumnos=array();
      $alumnos['items'] = array();

      $sql = "SELECT * FROM alumnos WHERE A_grado='$grade' and A_grupo='$group'";
      $query = $this->conn->query($sql);

      if(!$query){
        echo "<script>alert('imposible consultar');</script>";
      }else{
        while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()){
          array_push($alumnos['items'], array(
            'ncontrol'=> $row['A_Ncontrol'],'nombre'=> $row['A_nombre']));
        }
      }

      return $alumnos;
    }
  }

$html= '<table>
    <tr>
      <td>NUMERO DE CONTROL: </td><td>NOMBRE: </td>
    </tr>';
    foreach ($alumnos['items'] as $item){
    '<tr>
      <td>'.$item['ncontrol'].'</td><td>'.$item['nombre'].'</td>
    </tr>';
  }
$html .= '</table>';
}?>
```

me envia 2 errores

> Notice: Undefined variable: alumnos in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\QR_code\form_credenciales.php on line 65
>
> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\QR_code\form_credenciales.php on line 65

Comment: Buenas, lo que te esta indicando el error es que no existe la variable `$alumnos`. Por lo que veo , tienes un metodo que te devuelve a los alumnos `infoAlumnos()`, pero no veo donde lo llamas. Intenta declarar antes la clase `$creden = new creden()` y en el for pon `($creden -> infoAlumnos())['items']`. Espero que te sirva

Comment: gracias, la clase infoAlumnos(); estaba implementando en conDBconsul.php.
mi solucion fue implementar la consulta en el mismo php.
y lo del foreach no establa recorriendo bien el array